# How to find and replace a regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text and want to replace all `\w\(`, for example `myword(` to the same with a space, so it should be `myword (`. How to do that with `s///`? or is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$s = "myword( word2(";
$s =~s/(\w+)(\()/$1 $2/g;
print $s;
```

As from  @ikegami command. My above regex `\w+` will backtrack this is needless. And no need to group the `(`, because known one. So i changed my regex accordingly,

New RegEx

```
$s =~s/(\w)\(/$1 (/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
my $str = "myword(";
$str =~ s/(\w+)(\()/$1 $2/;
print $str, "\n";
```

Output:

```
myword (
```

Comment: Changing the OP's `\w` to `\w+` needlessly slows things down. (Consider the amount of backtracking needed to determine `foobar!` doesn't match.) And you can completely avoid the second capture to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

Use look ahead:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(\w)(?=\()/$1 /' <<< 'word('
word (
```

Or look ahead together with look behind:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=\w)(?=\()/ /' <<< 'word('
word (
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way will be to use `\K` i.e forget what you matched before:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = q{myword( myword2(};
$string=~s/\w\K\(/ (/g;
print $string,"\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s/\w\K\(/ (/g   # 5.10+
```

or

```
s/(\w)\(/$1 (/g
```

or

```
s/(?<=\w)\(/ (/g
```

The first is much faster than the other two, but all are faster than the other correct solutions provided. (Not sure which is the fastest of the second and third.)